# Is it possible to configure the Java Cryptography Architecture to use Azure Key Vault as a crypto provider?

Tags: azure

We are currently using [ForgeRock](https://www.forgerock.com/) as an Identity and Access Management solution, this is being hosted on Infrastructure-as-a-Service machines in Azure, i.e. [Virtual Machine Scale Sets](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/virtual-machine-scale-sets/).  There is a requirement to protect the private keys using FIPS-140-2 validated Hardware Security Modules, HSMs, research has indicated that the only way to achieve that is to use [Azure Key Vault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/key-vault/).

Now having looked into how to configure an [HSM with ForgeRock](https://forum.forgerock.com/topic/is-hsm-supported-as-keystore/) this appears to be possible because you can change the Java Cryptographic Extensions provider to use the `SunPKCS11` provider and configure the provider itself to communicate with the HSM to provide crypto offload.

Is it possible to do the same with Azure Key Vault? For reference, Azure Key Vault doesn't support JCE or PKCS11 natively, despite being backed by [Thales nShield family of HSMs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/key-vault/key-vault-hsm-protected-keys).

Comment: Is your query resolved? Have you integrated with Azure Key-vault using Java?

Comment: We ended up creating a Java JCE provider that’s mapped the JCI to Azure’s REST API. https://github.com/hmcts/azure-keyvault-jca-provider